# What's wrong in my code? (Option yes/no custom in magento module)

Tags: magento-1.9

i have following codes with me

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
        <?php //StockMessages disabled ?>
<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable') == 0): ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

        <?php //StockMessages enabled ?>
<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable') == 1): ?>
 <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                <p class="availability in-stock"><?php $quantity=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); if($quantity<= Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty')) { echo  Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_message') . intval($quantity) ;} else { echo "In stock"; }  ?> </span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It seems that the 2 conditions that are available in my code is not working. ie

```
<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable') == 0): ?>
      ..
<?php elseif(!Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable') == 1): ?>
      ..
<?php else : ?>
     ..
<?php  endif; ?>
```

As far as I know `0` is used for for `NO` and `1` is used for `YES` conditions (in default magento).

How can I resolve this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if:
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable');

Is returning 0 or 1 (false or true). If return blank are you calling the wrong configuration. You can check the right config name in etc/system.xml file of your module.

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::getStoreConfigFlag()` might be better in this instance, as you are looking at conditional operators.

Also, you have a bit of confusing logic in your code.

```
<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable') == 0): ?>
//  False equals true?
```

This might be better

```
<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable')): ?>
// zero is interpreted as false in php
```

Overall, this would get you where you're going:

```
<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable')): ?>
   // do something if true
<?php else: ?>
   // do something if false
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

where

***sectionName***, ***groupName*** and ***fieldName*** are present in `etc/system.xml` file of your module

Comment: i use this code for YES option or for NO? i insert in the if but in new code ALWAYS shows "in stock", check http://pastebin.com/PX7Qsbwq (sorry i dont know how insert code here in this website, i go to read faq :)

Comment: replace `<?php if($configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable')): ?>` with `<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('stockitems/option/stockmessages_enable')): ?>`. Actually whats the issue you are facing now ?

Comment: if i use your changes, without ! in mage:: getstoreconfig, the messages are hide , nothing changes is visible, set yes or no, nothing .... why? thanks